# Some contact names missing from Messages, but initials still visible?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, contacts

This is recent (popped up in the last week), and I don't think it came up with any updates; most recent thing I can think of is watchOS 4.2. I'm on the iPhone 7, with iOS 11.2.

Only in my Messages app, some contact names are still visible, but most contact names have been replaced with their phone numbers. The contact "picture" on the side still has their initials though.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Contacts issue screenshot]

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what are you trying to do? Change the picture/initials or have the contact show up with their name rather than phone number?

Comment: I would like to have the contact show up with their names on top of the message previews instead of the phone number. It used to show names but switched to showing numbers recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem for weeks and tried numerous solutions like toggling on and off the short names, adding a country prefix to the number, etc. What finally worked for me was toggling OFF icloud contacts under Settings.