# Macbook not showing contact names in messages?

Tags: macos, messages, contacts, ventura

I have the 2023 Macbook Air running MacOS13.4. I synced my apple ID from my iphone to my macbook, and in the contacts app on my macbook, I can see all my contacts; however, in the messages app on my macbook, it only shows the digits and not the contact name.

How can I get the contact names to show in the messages app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some contact names missing from Messages, but initials still visible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308909/some-contact-names-missing-from-messages-but-initials-still-visible)

Comment: @LincD. no. there are no initials in my case

Comment: Yes, this happened to me too when I bought a new Mac in July. I tried going to Messages Settings (press ⌘+,) and enable and disable iCloud for iMessage. It then showed something like "Fetching data from iCloud" but it didn't result in anything.

Comment: @Thinkr do you think it's an OS issue or it's specific to the new macs? I have 2021 work macbook but don't want to login with my apple id to check if it also has the issue

Comment: In the Language & Region panel of System Preferences, change the region to another one, then change it back. Does that have any effect?

Comment: @LincD. just tried and no change

Comment: @roulette01 Well, I would say (pure guess) that it's with the OS, normally, the hardware doesn't influence this. But it could also be an Apple ID problem. To fix it, I just exported all contacts from my iPhone contacts, removed all existing contacts from my Mac and then imported the contacts file to my Mac. Weirdly enough, when I exported the contacts to the Mac directly, they synced perfectly with the iPhone. I think it was just some kind of bug with iCloud syncing.

Comment: Next step, boot in safe mode and test. Failing that, sign out of iCloud and iMessage, then sign back in.